# Ajax to call Symfony controller

Tags: ajax, symfony

I'm trying to call a method with ajax.
ajax connection is succeed and no error message was appeared.

the JS code

```
$("[id^=changeStatus]").each(function(){
$(this).on("click", function(){
  const id = $(this).data('id');
  console.log(id);
  $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "{{url('change_order_status')}}",
          data: id,
          async: false,
  })
  .done(function() {
    console.log('success');
  })
  .fail(function () {
    console.log('error');
  });
});
```

but the method in the controller seemingly not working.
controller

```
/**
 * @Method("POST")
 * @Route("/%eccube_admin_route%/", name="change_order_status")
 * @param $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse
 */
public function changeOrderStatus(Request $request)
{
    if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        throw new BadRequestHttpException();
    }
    
    $this->logger->info("it's working");
    dump($rquest);

}
```

I don't know what is wrong with it.
Please help.

I insert the js to every pages as an snippet is that's why it doesn't work properly.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried to make it work? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Can you share more details about the request itself? Is it posted to the URL you expect to pot to? Does it contain the data it should? What does your network tab tell you about the request?

Answer (score 0):

You must return an instance of Response class in a controller . So here, what you can do is to return a JsonResponse

```
return new JsonResponse($request->getContent());
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the ajax response in your development tool ?

Comment: sure. I added screenshots of the console. thanks for asking me.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this.

```
$("[id^=changeStatus]").each(function(){
$(this).on("click", function(){
  const id = $(this).data('id');
  console.log(id);
  $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "{{ path('change_order_status') }}",
          data: {
             id : id
          },
          async: false,
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
    console.log('success');
  })
  .fail(function () {
    console.log('error');
  });
});
```

```
/**
 * @Route("/%eccube_admin_route%/", name="change_order_status", methods={"POST"})
 * @param $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse
 */
public function changeOrderStatus(Request $request)
{
    if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        throw new BadRequestHttpException();
    }
    
    $this->logger->info("it's working");

    $id = $request->request->get('id');

    // Try to dump your request
    // dd($request);
    
    return $this->json([
        'success' => true
    ]);
}
```

I just don't know what **eccube_admin_route** mean.
And don't forget to extend **AbstractController** in your controller class

[image: Try to dump your controller object and use symfony debugbar to open your ajax request, click on url columns]

This is example from my project. Try to dump your controller object and use symfony debugbar to open your ajax request, click on url columns

Comment: What is "this"? Can you add some explanation to your answer, such that others can learn from it? What have you changed, and why?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice but sorry it still doesn't work. "eccube_admin_route" is the config page of an EC site. Ajax returns the html data of the eccube_admin_route page. I don't know why it can not call the method.

Comment: I insert the js to every pages as an snippet is that's why it doesn't work properly?

Comment: I changed "/%eccube_admin_route%/"  to "/%eccube_admin_route%/order/ajax"  and the function looks called by ajax. Thank you. However , on `$id = $request->query->get('id');`  **$id gonna be null** Could you teach me how to fix it please.

Comment: Hi, please try `$id = $request->request->get('id');`, I forgot you use post on the  ajax method.